# Como puedo personalizar el estilos de los radiobuttons en Android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, radiobutton, radiogroup

estoy intentado hacer un panel de filtros para un recyclerview pero no se como puedo modificar el estilo de los radiobuttons para poder hacer una lista seleccionable.

tampoco se si la idea de usar radiobuttons es correcta, de antemano les doy las gracias.

[image: Quiero lograr algo como esto]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes utilizar el widget llamado **chip**  que viene integrado en el nuevo set de componentes de material design.

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
android:id="@+id/chip4"
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/chip_text" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Para más detalles, puedes revisar este instructivo que indica como  utilizar el componente.](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/chips-material-components-for-android-46001664a40f)

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad, investigaré y lo intentaré.